# Is there any alternative to peptone and beef or yeast extract?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology, growth-media

I am trying to start a small microbiology project and I need a growth culture for bacteria. I do not want to use the costly nutrient agars you can buy online. I would like to create my own nutrient agar using the recipe below, but I do not have peptone. I found a paper that seems to be using extruded beans instead of peptone and beef or yeast extract.

Is possible to edit the recipe below and use extruded beans instead of peptone and beef or yeast extract?

This is the article about beans:
[Batista, K. A., Bataus, L. A. M., Campos, I. T., & Fernandes, K. F. (2013). Development of culture medium using extruded bean as a nitrogen source for yeast growth. Journal of microbiological methods, 92(3), 310-315.](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167701213000067)

[The exact recipe I would like to edit](https://microbiologyinfo.com/nutrient-agar-composition-preparation-and-uses/).

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [ask] effectively on this site. I've edited your post for clarity, please check to make sure I've preserved your intent. In addition, please add in a summary of the 'recipe' since questions are expected to be self-contained (and thus should not require other users to follow links to external sites). ——— Since you now seem to be posting using two separate accounts, you may find this information on [merging accounts](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to be of interest ...

Answer (score 0):

There is an article about using cheap substitutes for peptone, one of the main ingredients of culture medium as a nitrogen-source. The authors used coconut cake (meal), ground-nut or gingelly cake which worked just as fine as the peptone.

The article is: An indigenous substitute for peptone as the
ingredient of culture media. by Raghavendra Rao et al. 2020 (ISSN: 2456-1045).